# How do you display php errors to the web browser in GAE?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, error-handling

Errors in Google App Engine are being suppressed and not displayed to the browser even if error reporting is on. The html that would normally be displayed to the browser is showing in the log files.

The following code should generate a error

```
<?php
  error
  phpinfo();
?>
```

When curling the page no content is returned just a 500 response code.

```
$ curl -i http://localhost/test.php

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Server: Development/2.0
Date: Fri, 02 Aug 2013 18:24:49 GMT
```

The php.ini for this application has `display_errors = On` and phpinfo correctly shows when called from within the app.

The expected behavior is output like this

```
$ php-cgi54 test.php 

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.14
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-parse-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'phpinfo' (T_STRING) in /Users/example/test/test.php on line     <i>3</i></th></tr>
</table></font>
```

Comment: Not sure if it's possible in GAE, but why do you want to show the error directly on output instead of following the logs? The current behavior is better for security while you can still debug relatively easy using the log.

Comment: I would probably have it off for production but it would be really nice for local development using SDK dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

In production we disable displaying errors for you app if it is being accessed by a normal user, for security reasons. This is regardless of the php.ini setting.

If the user accessing the app is one of the app administrators then we will display the errors to help you debug.

Of course, all errors are sent to the request log so you can go there and retrieve them.

Comment: What defines production vs development? I have this code running on my local dev server and then a copy running on appspot. From what you said the error should not be shown when calling from appspot.

`print "App ID: " . $_SERVER['APPLICATION_ID'] . "\n";
print "Server: " . $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] . "\n";
print "Is Admin: " . $_SERVER['USER_IS_ADMIN'] . "\n";
print "Display Errors? " . ini_get('display_errors') . "\n";
$test = null;
$foo = array_merge($test, $test);`

When curling the local and appspot page the error is shown. Here are the [responses](http://pastebin.com/XmME1sZ2)

Comment: I found PHP Exception is represented as object sometimes and string in other times (shown in stackdriver logging), do you have any recommendation to get Exception object for all PHP Exceptions? (I prefer use Exception object instead of string, because object has more information, even though there are a lot of Exceptions represented by string in logs)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if GAE will allow that through normal php directives.

You may be able to bypass it with:

```
<?php
function display_error($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext) {
  //echo desired info here
  die();
}

set_error_handler("display_error");
?>
```

GAE may block this as well, but it's pretty easy to give it a try

**Edit:**

More info on fatal errors, since that is the type of error you describe in your question, and may not be handled by `set_error_handler();`
[How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)

Answer (score 0):

If your application exceptions should appear in your App Engine Logs, you can directly use [Google Stackdriver Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/) to see at a glance the errors of your PHP application.

No setup is required since it is auto-configured for App Engine.

Access Error Reporting for your project at https://console.cloud.google.com/errors